# Get price for item on steam community market

Tags: php, steam, steam-web-api

I am trying to somehow get the lowest price of a item on the Steam Community Market, I don't seem to see a soloution in the Steam Web API.

So I was hoping one of  you smart heads had a solution?

http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/AK-47%20%7C%20Vulcan%20%28Battle-Scarred%29

ex. on that site, the lowest priced auction's price I would like to have returned in PHP.

or even to do it in Objective C would be awesome, thanks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats how you get the prices for the first page,work a way to identify the currency/loop threw the pages/sort them and you are done.

```
<?php
$string = file_get_contents('http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/AK-47%20|%20Vulcan%20%28Battle-Scarred%29');
$attrList = explode('<span class="market_listing_price market_listing_price_with_fee">',$string);
$N=count($attrList);
for ($i=1;$i<$N;$i++){
    $prices[$i-1] = explode('</span>',$attrList[$i])[0];
}
print_r($prices);
?>
```